# Regex expression to match unique tags in list of phrases

Tags: regex

I have a comma separated list of phrases, each of which starts with a keyword and I want to match the set of unique keywords, but only want each keyword to appear once.  For example, my set of phrases may look something like "A-B-C or cats or kittens, A-B-D or dogs or puppies, A-Q-C or pigs or cows, A-B-C or carrots or celery, Z-B-C or zebras or elephants".  I want the result set to be

A-B-C or cats or kittens
A-B-D or dogs or puppies
A-Q-C or pigs or cows

I'm matching on keywords that start with "A" but only want each keyword to appear once.  So the phrase that starts with "Z-B-C" doesn't match, and the 2nd time "A-B-C" appears should be ignored.

I'm a regex novice and have been trying to find examples here but haven't found anything that quite works.  My current expression of "A[^,]*" correctly pulls the phrases that start with "A" but the second instance of "A-B-C" comes along as well.  I could code this in python or something else, but I need to do this inside another application that has a regex expression evaluator rather than with an external program.  Thanks!

Comment: Why no `Z-B-C or zebras or elephants` in the output?

Comment: I'm wanting to pull the phrases that start with a known keyword, in this case the keyword is starting with the letter "A".  So the phrase starting with "Z-B-C" doesn't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/((A-.-.)(?!.*\2).*?),/g
```

https://regex101.com/r/tL0hP8/1

This takes the pattern you are looking for in the second capturing group, and negative lookahead asserts that there is no other patterns that match it going forward, then it takes the rest of the string before the next comma and captures it in the first capturing group. Notice how you can't just use

```
/(A-.-.(?!.*A-.-.).*?),/g #wrong
```

as it would only match `A-Q-C or pigs or cows.`

For more about capturing groups: http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html

For more about lookaround assertions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: That was pretty darn close.  Actually it was exactly right for the example I had given.  I had simplified my test data and instead of single characters separated by dashes the keyword is actually longer words so once I tried it with more "real" data it didn't work, but a little tweaking to change the A-.-. into A-\w*-\w* to match words instead of single characters things worked fine.  Thanks for the answer!